# Visualizing a Keras Model with Tensorboard in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, graph-visualization

I am learning to visualize a Keras model using Tensorboard with Tensorflow 2.0

For a reproducible example:

```
inputs = Input(shape = (train_data.shape[1], ))
x1 = Dense(100, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', activation = 'elu')(inputs)
x1a = Dropout(0.5)(x1)
x2 = Dense(100, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', activation = 'elu')(x1a)
x2a = Dropout(0.5)(x2)
x3 = Dense(100, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', activation = 'elu')(x2a)
x3a = Dropout(0.5)(x3)
x4 = Dense(100, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', activation = 'elu')(x3a)
x4a = Dropout(0.5)(x4)
x5 = Dense(100, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', activation = 'elu')(x4a)
predictions = Dense(1)(x5)
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = predictions)

@tf.function
def traceme(x):
    return model(x)


logdir = "log"
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
# Forward pass
traceme(tf.zeros((1, train_data.shape[1])))
with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.trace_export(name="model_trace", step=0, profiler_outdir=logdir)
```

How can I proceed from this point to get the visualization?

---

When I run the command from  my Jupyter Notebook I get an error message:

```
%load_ext tensorboard.notebook
%tensorboard --logdir logs

ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).
Contents of stderr:
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder import beholder_plugin
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder.beholder import Beholder
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\beholder.py", line 199, in <module>
    class BeholderHook(tf.estimator.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'estimator'
```

When I run it from the terminal window again I get an exception:

[image]

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>tensorboard --logdir log
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder import beholder_plugin
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder.beholder import Beholder
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\beholder.py", line 199, in <module>
    class BeholderHook(tf.estimator.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'estimator'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could you advise me how I proceed from this point to get the
>   visualization?

In jupyter notebook,

```
# Load the TensorBoard notebook extension.
%load_ext tensorboard

%tensorboard --logdir log
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/graphs#graphs_of_tffunctions

You can also do this from a terminal by running this command,

```
tensorboard --logdir log
```

and opening `'localhost:6006'` from a web browser.

If the Anaconda environment is correct, check this link for a way to resolve the exception: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2067#issuecomment-478140779

Comment: Thank you but I am getting exceptions.  See my updated post.

Comment: For jupyter notebook, you have to load the tensorboard extension, please see updated answer.

Comment: Regarding the exception, are you in the right tensorflow environment? Are your packages installed in the base environment of Anaconda or a different one?

Comment: I think I overcame the problem by updating tensorboard.  I have still some questions but I will open a new post.  I will mention it here once I am done.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: My new post is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115212/using-tensorboad-to-monitor-training-real-time-and-visualize-the-model-architect